# HTML custom font using images?

Tags: html, fonts

I'm not sure how to explain this so I'll start from the beginning. I'm trying to build a website which I want to have custom font. However the font I want to use is the same font I designed for my game. And so the font changing tags won't have my custom sprite.

The only way to achieve my custom font would be to load sprites of each character and program the font into my website. However I have no idea where I would begin with such a task. Or even if the task is possible. I achieved it once but it was very inefficient.

So I thought I'd ask the people at stackoverflow if this is achievable at all or if I am just have a daydream. So, can a custom font using images be done?

Comment: If you can convert your images to vectors, you can use http://icomoon.io

It's not possible to use bitmaps (e.g. multiple colors) in custom fonts.

Comment: Fonts are simply collections of vector images.

Comment: Still trying to get the SVGs I made in Inkscape to appear in the icomoon. They will show the characters in Internet Explorer but not in icomoon. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The one way I can think of doing this is if you can somehow convert your sprites to SVG. Once in SVG, it seems a relatively simple way to create a font from those SVGs as outlined [here.](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/)

Comment: Looks like a great idea. I do have a problem though. I can create the SVGs and when opened in a web browser they appear. But when I import them into IcoMoon they disappear. Any idea why this would happen? I followed the guide correctly